# How to submit some text

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to submit (on mousedown) some text which takes up the class "current" when hovered:

```
$("#SomeDynamicMenu li").live("mousedown", function() {

        var SearchTerms = $('li.current').text();
        $('#SomeForm').submit(SearchTerms);

});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#SomeDynamicMenu li").live("mousedown", function() {
    var SearchTerms = $('li.current').text();
    $('#anyHiddenInForm').val(SearchTerms);
    $('#SomeForm').submit();
});
```

Comment: Why do you suggest AJAX? I'd rather suggest using a real <a>-Link, but I suppose it depends on the context.

Comment: Can you please take a look at it again, it doesn't work because there is nothing to submit...Its not 'SearchTerms' that needs to be submitted but the text of 'li.current' SearchTerms doesn't mean anything when taking out like that

Comment: @giraff, I confused 'mousedown' and 'mouseover' :)

Comment: There is a jQuery `submit` method. But is is for registering event handlers and triggering the `submit` event.

Comment: Thank's, I haven't got it to work yet because the form has `action="http://www.google.com/search` I need to put two and two together but I think your code is accurate.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#SomeDynamicMenu li").live("click", function ()
{
    var SearchTerms = $(this).text();
    var form = $("#SomeForm");
    form.append('<input type="hidden" value="'+SearchTerms+'" name="SearchTerms" />');
    form.submit();
});
```

Then you'll be able to get your handy `$_POST["SearchTerms"]` variable in PHP containing the text of the clicked li. Also depending on what version of jQuery .submit() may not work in certain browsers if your submit button has `name="submit"`.

NB: Can easily be changed for "mousedown" rather than "click"

Comment: Your anwser is giving me error in dreamweaver in: form.append---

Comment: I get what you code, I did the same thing with an actual html input(display:none) but I don't like this because I believe there is a delay in the request

Comment: I don't mean to be condescending but if you're using dreamweaver, a hidden text input rather than a input of hidden type and the code that you started with, a fictional "delay in the request" is the least of your worries.

Comment: What more should I worry about..?

Comment: of course there is a delay because the code is a detour, rather than submitting the text on click its first doing other stuff. So what the heck are you talking about?